# AndroidStudio FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Failed to create Jar file C:\...\gradle-api-impldep-6.8.jar. > invalid stored block lengths

Tags: android, gradle, exception

So I just tried to create a new empty project and when I create it, it gives me this error and doesn't sync it and I even don't have the build.gradle module. The full error it gives me is this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\Samsung\.gradle\caches\jars-8\f63efd716e824b816dbd0b68fbcfe113\gradle-api-impldep-6.8.jar.
> invalid stored block lengths

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\Samsung\.gradle\caches\jars-8\f63efd716e824b816dbd0b68fbcfe113\gradle-api-impldep-6.8.jar.
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathBuilder.jar(ClasspathBuilder.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.instrument(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:137)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.transform(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:132)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.transform(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer$TransformFile.lambda$schedule$0(DefaultCachedClasspathTransformer.java:274)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.read(ByteStreams.java:910)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.readFully(ByteStreams.java:787)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.readFully(ByteStreams.java:770)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.impl.JdkZipEntry$1.run(JdkZipEntry.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.impl.JdkZipEntry$1.run(JdkZipEntry.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.impl.JdkZipEntry.withInputStream(JdkZipEntry.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.impl.JdkZipEntry.getContent(JdkZipEntry.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathWalker$ZipClasspathEntry.getContent(ClasspathWalker.java:115)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.lambda$visitEntries$1(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:150)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathWalker.visitJarContents(ClasspathWalker.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathWalker.visit(ClasspathWalker.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.visitEntries(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.lambda$instrument$0(InstrumentingClasspathFileTransformer.java:139)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathBuilder.buildJar(ClasspathBuilder.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.ClasspathBuilder.jar(ClasspathBuilder.java:53)
    ... 7 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? This is my first question so I hope I didn't mess anything. I am using Windows 7, don't know if this helps.